# Consensus Algorithms for multi-agent systems

Tags: consensus

What are the best web resources available to start learning about consensus algorithms? I tried reading IEEE research papers but couldn't understand it because of the level of mathematics used in it.

Answer (score 0):

Consensus is typically a problem solved in a layer below multi-agent systems, it is the fundamental problem in distributed systems, an abstraction-level below multi-agent systems. Consensus is the essential problem in distributed systems, and is required for implementing reliable communication, replication, leader election, agreement etc.

Multi-agent system literature typically reason about behavior and protocol of agents through more high-level protocols than consensus algorithms. Often the protocols on multi-agent system level talks about "coordination", "auctions", etc. rather than consensus. E.g in multi-agent system literature it is common to not even explicitly mention how consensus, and means of communication is managed, those are assumed to be implemented on a lower level.

If you are interested about consensus in distributed systems you can see the following literature.

- Paxos: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science), or the paper by the author of the algorithm: https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf
- Raft: https://raft.github.io/
- 2PC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol
- View synchrony: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_synchrony

Those are four different algorithms/approaches for consensus, the most fundamental one is Paxos. However, the papers might include some math so if you are not comfortable with that, try the wiki pages first, or try googling and you'll find blogposts.

If you want to read a shorter book on distributed systems as a general subject, including some chapters on consensus, I can recommend: http://book.mixu.net/distsys/ , this book contains minimal math as far as I remember.

If you are looking for any specific literature let met know, I've read quite a lot on this subject.

Best regards;